# CTreeCtrl: How to clear the focus of selected item

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

Am new to MFC, I want to replicate the exact <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> behavior to regular <kbd>Page Down</kbd>/<kbd>Page Up</kbd> keys without any supporting keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>). I have been trying to clear the focus of item which is getting selected automatically on striking the keys <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

I've tried with this code but its not working:

```
case VK_NEXT:   // pagedown
case VK_PRIOR:  // pageup
    lhItem = GetFocusedItem();
    if (IsSelected(lhItem))
    {
        CTreeCtrl::SetItemState(lhItem, 0, TVIS_SELECTED);
    }
    break;
```

Can anyone please help me in solving it

Comment: Please try to be less sloppy with your formatting in the future, and do read the [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: And where did you put "this code" ?

Comment: I've kept my code in                                                                                           void CiTreeCtrl::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags) {} function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code need to written in OnSelChanging & OnSelChanged Event Handler functions

```
void CTreeCtrl::OnSelchanging(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    HTREEITEM hNew = pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem;
    HTREEITEM hOld = pNMTreeView->itemOld.hItem;

    m_bOldItemSelected = hOld && (CTreeCtrl::GetItemState(hOld, UINT(TVIS_SELECTED)) & TVIS_SELECTED);

if (GetSelectedCount() > 1)
{
    if (m_bPgUpState || m_bPgDownState)
    {
        //Check the state of New Item
        if ((pNMTreeView->itemNew.state & TVIS_SELECTED))
        {
            // If the item is selected, so make sure OnSelchanged()
            // will "select" it !
            m_bNewItemSelected = TRUE;
        }
        else if (!(pNMTreeView->itemNew.state & TVIS_SELECTED))
        {
            // The New item is not selected, so make sure OnSelchanged()
            // will not "re-select" it !
            m_bNewItemSelected = FALSE;
            CTreeCtrl::SetItemState(hNew, UINT(~TVIS_SELECTED), UINT(TVIS_SELECTED));
        }
    }
}

void TreeCtrl::OnSelchanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NM_TREEVIEW* pNMTreeView = (NM_TREEVIEW*)pNMHDR;

    HTREEITEM itemNew = pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem;
    HTREEITEM itemOld = pNMTreeView->itemOld.hItem;
if ((m_bPgUpState || m_bPgDownState) && (GetSelectedCount() > 1)
    && (pNMTreeView->itemOld.hItem != NULL || pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem != NULL))
{
    // It had the focus so Keep selection at old item
    if (itemOld && m_bOldItemSelected)
    {
        CTreeCtrl::SetItemState(itemOld, UINT(TVIS_SELECTED), UINT(TVIS_SELECTED));
        m_bOldItemSelected = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do-not select the item if it is not selected
        CTreeCtrl::SetItemState(itemOld, UINT(~TVIS_SELECTED), UINT(TVIS_SELECTED));
    }

}
```

In this article you'll find solution for every thing about CTreeCtrl
[Full-Featured Tree Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11053/Full-Featured-Tree-Control)